# Babel keeps complaining: "british not defined, using English instead."

Tags: babel, warnings, blindtext

after having found nothing on google or here I have now resorted to my last hope: Asking myself.

Whenever I run a latex file (using pdflatex from MikTeX under Windows 7 x64) with `\usepackage[british]{babel}` I keep getting warnings from babel:

```
british not defined, using English instead.
```

This even happens in an absolute minimal file:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\title{Testtext}
\author{Me}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

\blindtext

\chapter{bar}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

I don't understand it. Can anyone give me some insight on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning is issued by [`blindtext`](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext), not [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel). That is because `blindtext` defines a number of language-specific documents, and currently only creates text corresponding to the following `babel`-like options:

- `english`
- `german`, `ngerman`
- `american`
- `catalan`
- `latin`
- `french`

Anything other than these may create a warning.

Comment: Well, thanks. That was stupid. Then again it kind of explains why I didn't find anything on google. But the name of the package in the warning would certainly help.